# Adding items to timeline plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, timeline

Hi Here I need to add items to timeline, I am using Shindiri Studio plugin (http://www.shindiristudio.com/demo/?item=Content%20Timeline_Wordpress). As per the document If am adding item as below

```
   <div class="timelineFlat tl1" id="timeLineContainerDiv">
                <div class="time_bg" style="background:#3b3f4f;">
                    <div class="item" data-id="05/01/2015" data-description="JANUARY, 5" >
                        <a class="image_rollover_bottom con_borderImage" data-description="ZOOM IN" href="images/flat/default/1.jpg" rel="lightbox[timeline]">
                            <span class="info_box">Info Box</span>
                        </a>
                        <h2>JANUARY, 5</h2>
                        <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exerc...</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
</div>
```

its working fine and getting response as below
[image]

But I want to add items dynamically(I get data after firing some API Call) through java script so I have written like below

```
function prepareHtml() {
    $('#timeLineContainerDiv').html('<div class="time_bg" style="background:#3b3f4f;"><div class="item" data-id="05/01/2015" data-description="JANUARY, 5" ><a class="image_rollover_bottom con_borderImage" data-description="ZOOM IN" href="images/flat/default/1.jpg" rel="lightbox[timeline]"><span class="info_box">Info Box</span></a><h2>JANUARY, 5</h2><span>sample text</span></div></div>');
}
```

But its not working, Below is the result(I think plugin is generating the timeline before I am appending the html).

[image]

Is there any other way of achieving this.

Comment: Where and how are you calling the prepareHtml() function? It should be executed as a callback of getting data function.

Comment: I am calling this in the success block of ajax call and I am calling this ajax call in head script tag

Comment: I am not able find any documentation section of the plugin. Check if the api has any onChange event,  where you can apply a redraw method or call the plugin again.

Comment: Thanks @Pazza22 with help of your suggestion I have initialized time line plugin just after appending html to div it works :)